# Trouble installing RMySQL on OSX Sierra

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to install RMySQL on Mac running OSX Sierra ver 10.12.2

I have reviewed the comments and suggestions provided for OSX Mavericks for a homebrew install of MySQL.  I had already installed MySQL with the MySQL/Oracle installer, so I attempted to replace the homebrew paths with the specific paths for my install per the following commands within R-Studio (R version 3.3.1 "Bug in Your Hair"):

```
Sys.setenv(PKG_CPPFLAGS = "-I//usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/include/")
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS="-L/usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/ -lmysqlclient")
```

I then attempted to install/build the RMySQL package as follows

```
install.packages("RMySQL", type="source")
```

I got the following error message

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.10.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54012 bytes (52 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 52 KB

* installing *source* package ‘RMySQL’ ...
** package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/mariadb-connector-c/include/mariadb
Using PKG_LIBS=-L/usr/local/opt/{openssl/lib,mariadb-connector-   c/lib/mariadb} -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -lz
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libmysqlclient was not found. Try installing:
* deb: libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu 16.04)
    libmariadbclient-dev (Ubuntu 14.04)
* rpm: mariadb-devel | mysql-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
* csw: mysql56_dev (Solaris)
* brew: mariadb-connector-c (OSX)
If libmysqlclient is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libmysqlclient.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RMySQL’
* removing    ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RMySQL’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RMySQL’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/6h/29_3qxmn0sd0n7zh7qr65txm0000gp/T/RtmpjmKIr5/downloaded_packages’
```

I think the installation is overwriting the environment variables that I set but I am not sure.

I am not that familiar with using HomeBrew as I have installed all of the software on my Mac using standard install packages.  I would prefer not to uninstall MySQL and reinstall via HomeBrew if possible since I already have several databases that are in use. I have some limited experience using Linux, but not enough to understand the underlying build process and environment variables being used to build RMySQL, so I don't know how to modify any of the other examples I have found for installing RMySQL that I have found on the site.

Comment: I have tried the instructions to sym link the libmysqlclient.20.dylib file to the R resources/lib folder suggested here [link](http://andorian.blogspot.com/2013/10/rmysql-on-osx.html) and here [link](https://gist.github.com/labeneator/6833376#file-rmysql_works-sh) but it still fails the same way

Comment: based on the error message I think I figure out that although I did not install mySQL via HomeBrew, the mariadb-connector-c still needs to be installed.  I installed it via HomeBrew as follows `brew install mariadb-connector-c`

Comment: Now I progress to the point that the linker can't find the ssl library.  I think this has something to do with apple deprecating the use of OpenSSL and I need to do something so the linker finds the OpenSSL that was installed with mariadb-connector-c but I don't know how.  Any help would be appriciated.  Once I get this to work, I will post the full solution to save someone else the 2 weeks I have been fighting this issue.